# Kafka : Improve performance when processing messages that require network call

Tags: apache-kafka

Here is the scenario.
My Kafka consumers consume messages from a topic.
The consumers should manually commit the offset after it has been correctly processed (`enable.auto.commit=false`).
Processing each message requires a few calculations (CPU) and a network call to an external service which can take several seconds.
So my consumers have low CPU impact and are spending most of their time waiting for an network response.
The order in which the messages are consumed is not important.

Currently, my topic has 10 partitions. I have 10 consumers in the same group id.

Given this scenario, I would like to improve the time performance and CPU efficiency.
I am using cloud services so I pay for time where my threads are just waiting (1 consumer = 1 thread).

My first (basic) idea was to increase the number of partitions and consumers to 100.
It indeed increases the processing speed but not the CPU efficiency because my consumers are still spending most of their time waiting.
Moreover, each new consumer is now consuming RAM for which I have to pay.

The "problem" here is that Kafka requires you to commit an offset and not a message.

For example, replacing Kafka with RabbitMQ (or an equivalent) and using reactive programming would allow me to have 1 consumer/thread which :

1. Take message 1
2. Start processing message 1 using cpu resource
3. Make the http call using reactive architecture for message 1 and configure a callback to acknowledge the message when done (or put it in a DLQ)
4. Take message 2 in the same thread
   ...

This way my CPU is always at 100%, the processing time is good and no message is lost. As stated above, the order in which the messages are processed is not important.

With Kafka, the problem with this solution is that if message N is successfully processed, it commits the offset after message N.
If my application crashes before the previous messages < N has been fully processed or put in a DLQ, I lose them and they are never processed.

For information, I am using Java + Spring for Apache Kafka but I don't think it matters for this problem.

Comment: Am not sure of Spring Kafka, but by Kafka architecture, as long as the batch is not committed by a consumer, it will be reprocessed, means you have duplicates for sure. May be in your case, when so many consumers in same group is processing in parallel, high chance that those partitions are getting assigned to another consumer threads and you are not seeing it being again processed by the same instance. May be you can check the logs of other instances Or just run a single instance, you will be able to find it. Still you have the issue, then its something really bad in the config/code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, you need to implemnt batch processing. Or maybe use (kafkajs for example have it built in)

Instead of taking a one message each time you can configure your application to take a batch of messages (lets say 100) and commit the latest offset when all of the messages have been processed successfully.

Keep in mind that you will probably need to configure the max.poll.interval.ms property in order to prevent rebalancing from occurring which can make your consumer instance to be kicked from the group and other instance will reprocess those messages.

BTW, it looks like you need ‘MQ’ maybe you look at Apache Pulsar it gives you both pub/sub and Message Queueing

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for your answer.  
Batch processing is indeed a good solution to this problem.  
Finally what I could do with Kafka is :  

[1] Take message 1-100  
[2] Start processing message 1-100 in parrallel using cpu resource  
[3] Make 100 non blocking http calls and configure a callback to put the error in DLT  
[4] When processing for all message is done, commit the batch offest in Kafka 
[5] Take message 101-200 ...  

This way, I am not limited to the number of partition of the topic.